# Create live queries for Google Sheet

Tags: sql, forms, google-sheets, google-sites

Trying to find a way to create a live query for Google Sheets, from *inside* a Google sites page. I know that you can use standard SQL query language to create dynamic table using sheets, but I'm trying to avoid creating 200+ different queries. So, I'd need to create a form that creates a query URL and opens the results in a child window.

Sites has nothing to create forms in it, and Google forms only wants to create Spreadsheets of responses, not create queries for current sheets.

Btw, I'd love to use a different host/builder app but this is what I've been saddled with. So, can this be done?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a form with google SP , you can use Javascript with App engine to use queries for Google SP. You can show data with query.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference

Or ou can use Google script with htmlservice.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

I don't think google form is very interesting for that.

Comment: Your first ink is to the Google Charts API which would be helpful if I was parsing numerical or chartable data, but I'm not. So thank you, but that's not gonna work. Your second link is actually genius... but way more work that I wanted to put into this project. I found a gadget that will load an iframe, so I guess I will do all of my scripting in that. Thanks again!!